# Change log level in logback at run time via external property file

Tags: java, logback, weblogic12c

I want to change the log level without restarting the server. I use `weblogic` server. For this I thought to pass the log level from a external file (`LOGBackIncludedFile.xml`) and give this file path in the logback `<include file>`. 
I cannot hard code the path, as the path is different in `Dev`, `UAT`, `Production`. I want to include this file in a location inside `Weblogic 12C` server. So I can change log level without touching `ear` file.

```
<configuration  scan="true"  scanPeriod="30 seconds">

   <include file="../../LOGBackIncludedFile.xml" />
   <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender" >
       <encoder>
         <pattern>%date %-5level [%logger] > %msg%n</pattern>
       </encoder>
  </appender>

  <root level="${root.level:-DEBUG}">          
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
  </root>  
</configuration>
```

Below is the `LOGBackIncludedFile.xml`

```
<included>
  <property value="INFO" name="root.level"/>
</included>
```

when I use this existing xml I get this error.

```
 java.io.FileNotFoundException: /usrXX/appXX/oracle/product/XXX/domains/XXXDomain/../../LOGBackIncludedFile.xml
```

My question is how can I set external file path dynamically in the logback.xml. The path should be to the specific `weblogic` `instance`. As I put the external file into my instance.

eg :  `/usrxx/appxx/oracle/product/XXX/domains/xxxDomain/servers/myInstance/`

Comment: You can change the log level through the admin console, WLST, or JMX...  Something like http://176.34.122.30/blog/2010/04/22/dynamically-changing-log-level-with-weblogic-log4j-jmx-and-wlst/   Does that work for you or are you asking something else?

Comment: @DisplayNameismissing   something like this. But I cannot change any server setting. So I am thinking of an simple way of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

Set the file path as below. This is for weblogic 12C.

```
 <include optional="true" file="${DOMAIN_HOME}/servers/${SERVER_NAME}/LOGBackIncludedFile.xml" />
```