# Change Log level at runtime without server restart?

Tags: java, logging, logback, slf4j

I am using the logback as implementation with SL4j interface. Here is the configuration

```
<appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>logs/prod.log</file>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">          
        <FileNamePattern>logs/prod.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log</FileNamePattern>
        <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
            <maxFileSize>700MB</maxFileSize>
        </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
    </rollingPolicy>
</appender>


    <logger name="com.ecom" additivity="false" level="ERROR">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    </logger>
```

I want to change the level to Info or debug at runtime through configuration or external property change in production without restarting the server. Is it possible ?

FYI ,I am using  Weblogic as application server and also Spring frameworks for other purposes >

Comment: But this is programmatic approach i am looking for configuration/property file change

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change log level in logback at run time via external property file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30976870/change-log-level-in-logback-at-run-time-via-external-property-file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Variable substitution](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html#variableSubstitution) is your friend here. [Default values for variables](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html#defaultValuesForVariables) should be helpful as well.

See also [variable scoping](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html#scopes).

Comment: in the boh the examples you mentioned, variable substitution is used to specify where log file will be created. How it can be used to change the log level at run time ? Do you mean i should create external properties file like `<property file="src/main/java/chapters/configuration/variables1.properties" /> which will contain some property like LOG_LEVEL=DEBUG` and then use it `<root level="${LOG_LEVEL}">` ?

`

Comment: Variable substitution works for the "level" attribute as well. I also modified my answer above.

Answer (score 2):

What you can try is to include another file (outside your webapp) that overrides the config in your logback.xml.

```
<configuration scan="true" scanPeriod="30 seconds">
  <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>logs/prod.log</file>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">          
      <FileNamePattern>logs/prod.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log</FileNamePattern>
      <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
         <maxFileSize>700MB</maxFileSize>
      </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
    </rollingPolicy>
  </appender>

  <logger name="com.ecom" additivity="false" level="ERROR">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
  </logger>

  <include optional="true" file="/tmp/logbackDynamic.xml"/>

</configuration>
```

Then your /tmp/logbackDynamic.xml could look like this if you want DEBUG loggings for com.ecom.SomeClass

```
<included>
  <logger name="com.ecom.SomeClass" level="DEBUG">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
  </logger>
</included>
```

Now Logback will check every 30 seconds if you changed your config in /tmp/logbackDynamic.xml, and reload it. If you want to return the original log level, just remove the line between the  tags and Logback will ignore the DEBUG level. You could even delete the file because of optional="true".

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to externalize the logger level

1. One at with system level property i.e. `java -Dlogback.configurationFile=/pathToconfig.xml`. See [How to externalize the log level](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html#configFileProperty)
2. `<root level="${log.level:-Error}">`. Then set the system level property `-Dlog.level=DEBUG`